# Phone calls seems to be from viber while they are not!

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, viber-messenger, samsung-galaxy-j5

It strange to say but it happens to me often when people call me from italy only(*This probably might happen from other countries as well*). They call me in their cell phone while at my smartphone it comes as a viber call.
So I open the viber calling and continue to talk to them, and I ask if they are calling me from viber but they say: - No I am just using simple call option.

I am using samsung galaxy j5 2016

Does anybody have any idea why this might happen ?
Should I check something into my phone or it has to be due to their payment plan or something ?

Comment: I guess you could select different sounds for incoming calls, for different apps... Would that help you?

Comment: I think I found the solution in viber app. Going to settings > calls and messages > viber in calls. It was checked so I unchecked it because it says: - **Receive regular incoming calls with viber when possible**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution in viber app. Going to settings > calls and messages > viber in calls. It was checked so I unchecked it because it says: - Receive regular incoming calls with viber when possible